# How do I compare two messages sent in a chat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
User 1: nuclear
User 2: reactor
```

I want to be able to compare these two messages; but, I'm having some trouble: I just don't know how to save the second message into a variable. I've tried using `wait_for()`, not sure if this is the way to do it or if i'm using it correctly.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Shiritori(commands.Cog):
    """ Start a new word from the last letter of the one before. """

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        last_letter = message.content[-1]
        print(f"The first letter is {message.content[0]}")

        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message')
        print(f"The last letter is {msg}")

        if message.content[0] != msg[-1]:
            await message.delete()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Shiritori(client))
```

My plan is to save the last letter of user 1's word and compare it with the first letter of user 2's word and if they don't match, user 2's message would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding the question correctly. One way of overcoming this without having to use `wait_for` is by making use of the class' attributes:

```py
class Shiritori(commands.Cog):
    """ Start a new word from the last letter of the one before. """

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.lastletter = "a" # keeps track of the recent last letter here

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        firstletter = message.content[0]
        if firstletter.lower() == self.lastletter.lower():
            self.lastletter = message.content[-1]
            print(f"The new letter to start the word with is {self.lastletter}")
        else:
            await message.delete()
```

Additionally, you can add checks for only letting this happen in a specific channel/specific users etc.